# What are the "Treasures of the Dragon Kings"?

Tags: chinese

I found reference to the "Treasures of the Dragon Kings" whilst in this wiki article [on mythological objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mythological_objects).

> Ǒusībùyúnlǚ (Cloud-stepping Boots or Cloud-stepping Shoes), made of lotus fiber, these are one of the treasures of the Dragon Kings; Ào Ming gives them to Sun Wukong in order to get rid of him when he acquires the Ruyi Jingu Bang. (Chinese mythology)

What are the remaining treasures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes from the *[Journey to the West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West)*, when the monkey king [Sun Wukong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Wukong) "visited" the Dragon King of the East Seas for a weapon. Each of the dragon kings produced a treasure to appease him into leaving in a full set of armaments. Theses were:

1. The ***According-To-Your-Wishes Gold-Banded Rod***, from the Dragon King of the East Seas.
2. The ***Lotus-Threaded Cloud-Stepping Treads***, from the Dragon King of the North Seas.
3. The ***Golden Chainmail***, from the Dragon King of the West Seas.
4. The ***Phoenix-Winged Rose-Golden Crown***, from the Dragon King of the South Seas.

(These are my own translation, and I tried to be as literal as possible. Published translations of the *Journey* presumably have different names for these items.)

I wrote up a fuller post with the original text, but apparently the CJK ban is in effect again so I'm unable to post it. I'll amend this post with the item's proper names and the source text if/when the restriction gets rescinded.

Comment: Could I also get some details about the properties of the items? I'm assuming the Treads are the boots I found reference to and that the banded rod is probably the famous Monkey King rod that can be any length. Otherwise great answer and thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the magic rod in question. The rest are literally just random scraps of luxury clothing the dragon kings scraped together for the Monkey King, though. The is no word on them possessing any special qualities - the only other time they were ever mentioned was when Sun Wukong's attire was being described.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but alas good answer!